# How to tell windbg to connect stdin of a debugged process to a certain file?

Tags: windbg, stdin

I am starting an app from the debugger. How can I connect a certain file as the stdin of the debugged process?

**EDIT**

Here is the command line I use:

```
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -c "!sw;g;g" c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe
```

LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe expects some input on the stdin, but I want to supply it from file. It is a trivial redirection when the app is ran directly, but what do I do if I run it through windbg?

Comment: The $<, $><, $$<, $$><, and $$>a< commands read the contents of the specified script file and [use its contents as debugger command input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566261(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I am not talking about the debugger command input. I want the application being debugged to get its stdin from a file. Not the debugger.

Comment: [windbg cmd /c "app < input.txt"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102351)

Comment: `windbg /o cmd /c "cmd < input.txt"` MS forgot **-o** switch

Comment: Here is my command line as per your suggestion - `windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -o c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe -c "!sw;c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe < 1.txt" `

Comment: The debugger stats the application, but no redirection takes place.

Comment: windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -o **cmd** -c "c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe < 1.txt"

Comment: `-o cmd` tells windbg to debugs child process and launch cmd.exe `-c "c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe < 1.txt"` launch app.exe and redirect according [msdn](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102351)

Comment: OK, I guess this is the closest I have to an answer. Please, arrange it as an answer, so I could credit you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
windbg -logo c:\dumps\dbg.log -QY -awow64exts -o cmd -c "c:\dev\LocalDriverProxyConsole.exe < 1.txt"
```